# How to save and resume entering string into cells with openpyxl?

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I am translating Chinese table names into English with Openpyxl.
  I input translation in PyCharm console and I wish to save workbook whenever I want like Ctrl+S in other conditions.
  It seems Openpyxl.Workbook.Save('file.xlsx') saves the file and I can't enter another word.
  Is there a way for me to save whenever I want and then resume inputing process?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. Excel files are actually zip archives and zip archives cannot be altered in place.

Comment: Thanks. I then used the Workbook.save() and restarted the .py file I wrote to make do with it.